# Using Count[] on a numerical list with approximate numbers

Tags: matrix, pattern-matching, counting

I have a matrix, SpinOp, for which I obtain the `Eigensystem` using `{evalSpinOp,evecSpinOp} = Eigensystem[SpinOp]`. I need to convert the matrix to a numerical one because otherwise the eigenvectors I obtain are not normalized (I really need them normalized) - as confirmed by the documentation of `Eigensystem`.

Now, I'd like to display a table which gives the eigenvalues of this matrix along with their degeneracies (or multiplicity) for which I'm using this code :

```
Grid[{ 
  Insert[Keys[Counts@evalSpinOp], "EigenValues", 1], 
  Insert[Values[Counts@evalSpinOp], "Degeneracy", 1]}, 
 Frame -> All]
```

However, the function `Counts` only works well if the eigenvalues are exact numbers. When the eigenvalues are approximate numerical numbers then `Counts` doesn't detect the multiplicity of eigenvalues properly (it thinks that two occurrences of "-3" are different) - which is understandable.

Is there any way to use a single function which can accurately count the eigenvalues and their multiplicity? I'm aware that it is possible to use `Counts` by not converting the matrix to a numerical one, computing the eigenvalues, saving them and then converting the matrix to a numerical one. However, I'd like to avoid unnecessary clutter in an already complicated code.

Thanks!

Comment: You can try `Tally`, which accepts a test for equality.

Comment: @b.gates.you.know.what `Tally` has the exact same issue as `Counts` with numerical lists

Comment: You can use `Normalize` on the exact eigenvectors (`{evalSpinOp, evecSpinOp} = Eigensystem[SpinOp];
evecSpinOp = Normalize /@ evecSpinOp;`)

Comment: Maybe `Eigenvalues@N[mat, 16] // Counts`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 `Eigenvalues@N[mat, 16] // Counts` works, can you please include an explanation of why it works and add this as an answer?

Comment: It might help to (re-)numericize the values to coarse scale, e.g. `N[vals,5]`. Then see which are deemed "equivalent" at that precision.